# Is it okay to use 'static for references to Box in self referential structs?

Tags: rust, undefined-behavior, unsafe, self-reference

Given the code snippet below:

```rust
use std::{io::BufWriter, pin::Pin};

pub struct SelfReferential {
    pub writer: BufWriter<&'static mut [u8]>, // borrowed from buffer
    pub buffer: Pin<Box<[u8]>>, 
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use std::io::Write;

    use super::*;
    fn init() -> SelfReferential {
        let mut buffer = Pin::new(vec![0; 12].into_boxed_slice());
        let writer = unsafe { buffer.as_mut().get_unchecked_mut() };
        let writer = unsafe { (writer as *mut [u8]).as_mut().unwrap() };
        let writer = BufWriter::new(writer);
        SelfReferential { writer, buffer }
    }

    #[test]
    fn move_works() {
        let mut sr = init();
        sr.writer.write(b"hello ").unwrap();
        sr.writer.flush().unwrap();
        let mut slice = &mut sr.buffer[6..];
        slice.write(b"world!").unwrap();
        assert_eq!(&sr.buffer[..], b"hello world!".as_ref());

        let mut sr_moved = sr;
        sr_moved.writer.write(b"W").unwrap();
        sr_moved.writer.flush().unwrap();
        assert_eq!(&sr_moved.buffer[..], b"hello World!".as_ref());
    }
}
```

The first question: is it OK to assign `'static` lifetime to mutable slice reference in `BufWriter`? As technically speaking, it's bound to the lifetime of struct instances themselves, and AFAIK there's no safe way to invalidate it.

The second question: besides the fact that unsafe instantiation of this type, in test example, creates two mutable references into the underlying buffer, is there any other potential dangers associated with such an "unidiomatic" (for the lack of better word) type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is it OK to assign `'static` lifetime to mutable slice reference in `BufWriter`?

Sort of, but there's a bigger problem. The lifetime itself is not worse than any other choice, because there is *no* lifetime that you can use here which is really accurate. But it is not safe to *expose* that reference, because then it can be taken:

```rust
let w = BufWriter<&'static mut [u8]> = {
    let sr = init();
    sr.writer
};
// `sr.buffer` has now been dropped, so `w` has a dangling reference
```

> is there any other potential dangers associated with such an "unidiomatic" (for the lack of better word) type?

Yes, it's undefined behavior. `Box` isn't *just* managing an allocation; it also (currently) signals a claim of unique, non-aliasing access to the contents. You violate that non-aliasing by creating the `writer` and then moving the `buffer` — even though the *heap memory* is not actually touched, the move of `buffer` is counted invalidating all references into it.

This is an area of Rust semantics which is not yet fully nailed down, but as far as the current compiler is concerned, this is UB. You can see this if you run your test code under the Miri interpreter.

---

The good news is, what you're trying to do is a very common desire and people have worked on the problem. I personally recommend using [`ouroboros`](https://docs.rs/ouroboros/) — with the help of a macro, it allows you to create the struct you want *without writing any new unsafe code.* There will be some restrictions on how you use the `writer`, but nothing you can't tidy out of the way by writing an `impl io::Write for SelfReferential`. Another, newer library in this space is [`yoke`](https://docs.rs/yoke/); I haven't tried it.

Comment: Thanks Kevin for the detailed answer.
> But it is not safe to expose that reference 
Yes I understand, I just added pub modifier in order to prevent cargo from complaining about unused fields.
> You violate that non-aliasing by creating the writer and then moving the buffer
I see, but aside from violating this invariant, can it really cause some unexpected behavior? As we are only concerned with the address of the underlying memory slice, which stays stable, and I fail to imagine a case when moving `buffer` can somehow invalidate references to memory it points to.

Comment: I've run the test under Miri interpreter, and it does indeed complain about UB, which has to do retagging of value which doesn't exist on borrow stack. 

Also thanks for pointing out the ouroboros library, will definitely check it out.

Comment: @BaburMakhmudov "aside from violating this invariant, can it really cause some unexpected behavior?" — Yes. The optimizer is free to assume that paths that produce UB _never happen,_ and thus transform the program into something you didn't mean. For example, it could decide that `buffer` is never _actually written_ (since it is only written via the prohibited aliasing `&mut`) and thus delete the entire usage of the `BufWriter`. Or many other things — when a program is unsound (executes UB), the [principle of explosion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_explosion) is in action.